# Svelte app shows a blank page when import/export something to app.svelte

Tags: javascript, firebase, localhost, svelte

I'm developing a web page with svelte and firebase.
The very first 'Hello World!' page provided by svelte template(https://github.com/sveltejs/template) works very well.
btw I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L39XLne7EU8) Youtube video.
So the problem is when I modify the App.svelte, especially the script part, as the video says, then there's nothing but a blank page. It has the favicon and the title, but nothing on the page. It happens when I import or export something.
I checked that when I added firebase.js file to scr folder and not add `import { db } from './firebase.js';` to the script in App.svelte yet, it still works. So it's not the problem of js file, it's app.svelte.
And I didn't modify any other file in my project folder. All I did was creating firebase.js file and modifing app.svelte file.
The code in app.svelte is like below:

```
<script>
    import { db } from './firebase.js';
    let arrTest = [];
    db.collection("testdoc").onSnapshot(snapData => {
        arrTest = snapData.docs
    })
</script>

<main>
    <h1>Welcome to the page!</h1>
    <ul>
        {#each arrTest as testdocItem}
            <li>{testdocItem.data().name}</li>
        {/each}
    </ul>
</main>

<style>
...
</style>
```

and the firebase.js file fyi:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "~",
    authDomain: "~",
    projectId: "~",
    storageBucket: "~",
    messagingSenderId: "~",
    appId: "~",
    measurementId: "~"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();

export const db = firebase.firestore();
```

Thanks in advance.
Update: I tried to put the Firebase configuration code directly to the script of App.svelte, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you open the developer tools with F12 and see if any errors are in the console? If you're getting a blank page, there is likely a runtime error.

Comment: Ok I took a look and it turns out that 'firebase.analytics()' function causes the error(says Uncaught TypeError: firebase$1.analytics is not a function). It is weird because I checked the box that I'm gonna use google analytics and that line was in the config code. Anyway I removed that line and it works now. I gotta figure out the analytics part later..Thank you, Geoff!

Comment: Checking the box is only the first step, you'll also have to **import the SDK** which you're currently not doing. So the alternative to removing the analytics call is to add `import 'firebase/analytics'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you discovered you're getting an error that Analytics cannot be initialized.

Checking the box is only the first step to using Analytics in your code, you'll also have to **import the SDK** which you're currently not doing.

So the alternative to removing the analytics call is to add:

```
import 'firebase/analytics'
```